# How can I make it to select multiple items in custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I make it to select multiple items and search should be done based on typing in search box?  Only the matched items should visible in drop down list.

Here is my working code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.1"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    {{_id}}
    <search items="mydata" 
        prompt="Start typing a US state" 
        title="mydata.displayConfig[0].propertyName" 
        subtitle="abbreviation" id="_id" model="c" 
        on-selectupdate="onItemSelected()"></search>
</body>

</html>
```

genericsearch.html

```
<div class="multitext-wrap blue-border">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchModel" ng-keydown="selected=false" />
    <br/>
    <div class="items" ng-hide="!searchModel.length || selected">
        <div class="item" 
            ng-repeat="item in items" 
            ng-click="handleSelection(item)" 
            ng-class="{active:isCurrent($index)}" 
            ng-mouseenter="setCurrent($index)"
            style="cursor:pointer">
            <p class="tag-label">{{item.name}}</p><span class="tag-cross pointer" ng-click="removeOrg($index);">x</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.onItemSelected = function() {
        console.log('on selected', $scope._id);
    };

    $scope.mydata = [
        {
            "_id": "1",
            displayConfig: [{
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o1",
                    "propertyValue": "sree"
                }, {
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o2",
                    "propertyValue": "sravs"
                }, {
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o3",
                    "propertyValue": "sree"
                },

            ],
            "name": "Alabama",
            "abbreviation": "AL"
        }, {
            "_id": "2",
            displayConfig: [{
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o1",
                    "propertyValue": "yui"
                }, {
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o2",
                    "propertyValue": "juim"
                }, {
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o3",
                    "propertyValue": "aww"
                },

            ],
            "name": "Alaska",
            "abbreviation": "AK"
        }, {
            "_id": "3",
            displayConfig: [{
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o1",
                    "propertyValue": "fgt"
                }, {
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o2",
                    "propertyValue": "ertyu"
                }, {
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o3",
                    "propertyValue": "ghytt"
                },
            ],

            "name": "bmerican Samoa",
            "abbreviation": "AS"
        }, {
            "_id": "4",
            displayConfig: [{
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o1",
                    "propertyValue": "hjjhu"
                }, {
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o2",
                    "propertyValue": "rdrer"
                }, {
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o3",
                    "propertyValue": "xds"
                },
            ],
            "name": "drizona",
            "abbreviation": "AZ"
        }, {
            "_id": "5",
            displayConfig: [{
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o1",
                    "propertyValue": "errrr"
                }, {
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o2",
                    "propertyValue": "ddd"
                }, {
                    "fieldIndex": 2,
                    "propertyName": "o3",
                    "propertyValue": "nnnn"
                },
            ],
            "name": "crkansas",
            "abbreviation": "AR"
        }

    ];
});


app.directive('search', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            prompt: '@',
            title: '@',
            subtitle: '@',
            model: '=',
            onSelectupdate: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.handleSelection = function(selectedItem) {
                scope.model = selectedItem;
                scope.searchModel = selectedItem.name;
                scope.current = 0;
                scope.selected = true;
                $timeout(function() {
                    scope.onSelectupdate();
                }, 200);
            };
            scope.current = 0;
            scope.selected = true;
            scope.isCurrent = function(index) {
                return scope.current == index;
            };
            scope.setCurrent = function(index) {
                scope.current = index;
            };
        },
        templateUrl: 'genericsearch.html'
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi @harrini, I think you pasted the wrong code into the app.js part. If it's already a plunkr please could you post a link?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/YhDv7oNMR1ZrheSHalIQ?p=preview

Comment: It's not clear what's not working? This is the entire application. What specifically do you need assistance with?

Comment: in that we can select only one, but i need if i select the another item it should also display by side of first item without replacing before one, i mean have to select multiple items as "tags"